# shell script test a telnet connection

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, telnet, netcat

I'm Trying to make a scipt that checks if my own specific port is open and can be connected.

I tried doing it by netcat by

```
nc -vz localhost 25565
```

but this only tells me if the port is open.

I need to check if the port can be connected
I tried by telnet with:

```
sleep 2 | telnet localhost 25565
```

This connects to the port and then after 2 seconds got out.

The thing is if there is a way to save if the connection was successfully or not to then make an if or while

Comment: I know this can be badly done with save the output string of the connection and then making a comparison

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, an application may be listening on *localhost* but not on your external adapter, so it is possible you could connect to *localhost* but others would not be able to. For this reason, in your testing you should use your computer's IP address which is visible to the network rather than *localhost*. This should be listed in the output of `ip addr show`.

To see not only if it is possible to connect to the port, but information about the service running on it, I recommend nmap (replace `192.168...` with your IP):

```
nmap -A 192.168.0.101 -p 25565
```

Alternatively, to just confirm that an application is listening on that port:

```
netstat -tulpn |grep '\b25565\b'
```

Both of these could be included in a `while true; do ...; sleep 60; done` script.

Comment: +1 `nmap` is the tool for this.